# Combine subset of pandas frame to original frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have following `ModelFrame`

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ml as pdml
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'B': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]})
dfml = pdml.ModelFrame(df)

In[20]: dfml
Out[20]: 
    A   B
0   1   3
1   2   4
2   3   5
3   4   6
4   5   7
5   6   8
6   7   9
7   8  10
8   9  11
9  10  12
```

Added scaling

```
dfml['A'] = dfml.preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform(dfml['A'])
0   -1.566699
1   -1.218544
2   -0.870388
3   -0.522233
4   -0.174078
5    0.174078
6    0.522233
7    0.870388
8    1.218544
9    1.566699
```

After I got `train` and `test` datasets

```
X, Y = dfml.cross_validation.train_test_split()

        A    
4 -0.174078 
3 -0.522233 
7  0.870388
```

Eventually, I performed `fit` and `predict` and got

```
      A         PREDICTED
 4 -0.174078       8
 3 -0.522233       2
 7  0.870388       1
```

And right now, I want to combine my predicted result with original frame `dfml` and got final result as:

```
    A   B  PREDICTED
0   1   3  
1   2   4
2   3   5
3   4   6      2
4   5   7      8
5   6   8
6   7   9
7   8  10      1
8   9  11
9  10  12
```

Does it possible smth like `dfml = dfml.join(Y)` ? Or any other approach to use `inverse_transform`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dfml.join(Y)` should work, except that you have overlapping columns named `A`.

Try:

```
dfml = dfml.join(Y[['PREDICTED']])
```